# How does Thespian's Stage work with Urza's Saga?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a [Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage) and an [Urza's Saga](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urza%27s%20Saga). I copy the Urza's Saga with Thespian's Stage. It should become a Saga, if I'm not mistaken, and therefore start gaining the Saga chapter abilities. When the copied Urza's Saga hits level 3, with the trigger on the stack, I use the Thespian's Stage ability to turn the Thespian's Stage/Urza's Saga into another land. Do I still have to sacrifice the Thespian's Stage?

I'm guessing the answer is no because there's a ruling for Urza's Saga which says:

> Even though Urza's Saga is a land, it is also still a Saga, and it will be sacrificed after its last chapter ability resolves.

And if I turn Urza's Saga into another land, then it is no longer a Saga (but the third chapter ability otherwise resolves as normal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you won't have to sacrifice the [Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage), but it will retain both the added abilities, and the lore counters.

Rule *715.4* covers sacrificing a Saga once the number of lore counters exceeds the final chapter number, and has the requirement that the Saga permanent doesn't have an chapter ability currently on the stack, as the Thespian's Stage can respond to the triggered ability while it is still on the stack it will stop being a Saga before the final ability resolves.

Notably, because the lore counters remain, if the same Thespian's Stage was used to copy another [Urza's Saga](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urza%27s%20Saga) if would immediately be sacrificed.

---

> **715.4.** If the number of lore counters on a Saga permanent is greater than or equal to its final chapter number, and it isn’t the source of a chapter ability that has triggered but not yet left the stack, that Saga’s controller sacrifices it. This state-based action doesn’t use the stack.

Comment: "it will retain ... the added abilities" - of Urza's Saga? How? Normally with copying cards, only abilities of the last copied card is retained.

Comment: same what NotThatGuy said. Counters stay, because the card didn't leave the field, but tehre's nothing that would say that UrzasSaga abilities stay. Just like the first time Thespian copied UrzasSaga, and his abilities **have not stayed**, only UrzasSaga abilities showed up. Otherwise, Thespian's text would have no point in saying that the card retains copy-land ability.

Comment: Found: 706.11 https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr706/ which says, that the **effect tracks the card**, with a similar example of card destruction. It mentions a condition of "referring by name", in Sagas we have "referring by type", but I'd not be picky here. However, since Saga's destruction is explicitly a state-based effect, this effect literally ceases to exist when Thespain ceases to be Saga type and can't activate. Were the mechanic a triggered effect like "after adding counter, if it exceeds limit, destroy at end of turn", it would resolve, linger, track the card, and kill it.

Comment: I believe that "it will retain...the added abilities" is referring to the abilities granted by the chapter abilities I and II, which both say "Urza's Saga gains '<ability text>'". Each of those creates a separate effect that grants an ability to the permanent. Those effects are separate from the copy effect, and continue to apply after a new copy effect resolves.

Comment: Yes, because the abilities added by Urza's Saga apply in layer 6 and copy effects apply in layer 4, the abilities added by Urza's saga aren't "seen" by Thespian's Stage while the copying is taking place (this also means they don't get copied off an Urza's Saga that has had them applied)

Comment: Wait, are you saying that after Thespian's Stage copies another land, the new land still has Urza's Saga's 2nd ability (i.e. it can tap and make constructs)? If so, that sounds strong, wow.

Comment: Yes, because of the way CR 611 and CR 613 work the new land will still be granted the abilities setup while it was an Urza's Saga,
Additionally this will also function through a *Blood Moon* (the stage becomes a basic mountain but will still be granted the abilities), but not an *Alpine Moon* if it's played after the Saga abilities have resolved.